# jQuery UI dialog content is showing up in page itself

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I have jQuery UI dialog in my application and button click will open this jQuery UI dialog content define in Diag div. I have also other control on the same page like asp.net dropdown list. Problem I am having is jQuery UI dialog div content is showing up in page itself instead of on dialog pop up. Is there anything I need to do to make dialog div invisible on page.

```
    <asp:DropDownList ID="dd" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true">
        <asp:ListItem>asfasf</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>asfasf</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <input type="button" id="btnSaveAs" value="Submit" />
    <div id="Diag">
        Test text
    </div>
```

jQuery code

```
  $(function () {
        $('#btnSaveAs').on('click', function () {
            $("#Diag").dialog({
                resizable: false,
                width: 400,
                height: "auto",
                modal: true,
                title: 'new window',
                buttons: {
                    "Save Record": addUser,
                    Cancel: function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }
            });
        });
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply hide the content in `Diag`.

```
$("#Diag").hide();
```

Then let the dialog display the content when the button is clicked.

http://jsfiddle.net/mL29zsLh/

As an additional note, I would recommend moving the `dialog` event handler outside the `click` event so you are not attempting to reattach each time.

This could be placed in your `DOM` ready function as shown below.

```
$(function() {
     $("#Diag").dialog({
             resizable: false,
             width: 400,
             height: "auto",
             autoOpen: false,
             modal: true,
             title: 'new window',
             buttons: {
                "Save Record": addUser,
                 Cancel: function () {
                     $(this).dialog("close");
                 }
             }
      });
});
```

Notice the addition of `autoOpen: false`.  Then simply open the dialog via:

```
$("#btnSaveAs").on("click", function() {
     $("#Diag").dialog("open"); 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mL29zsLh/1/

Answer (score 1):

You have to initialize dialog first with `autoOpen` parameter set to `false`. Don't do it inside `click` block.
See working fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/zs1acjh3/

Then, on button click, invoke the dialog:
`$("#Diag").dialog("open");`

Answer (score 1):

You need to `initialize` it before and set its `autoOpen` to `false` to hide it on page load. On clicking of button you can just show `dialog box` as below:

```
var dialog;
$(document).ready(function(){
     dialog = $("#Diag").dialog({
                autoOpen:false, //set this to hide at initial stage
                resizable: false,
                width: 400,
                height: "auto",
                modal: true,
                title: 'new window',
                buttons: {
                    "Save Record": addUser,
                    Cancel: function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }
     });
})
```

and on `click` of `button` you need to open the `dialog` as below:

```
$('#btnSaveAs').on('click', function () {
     dialog.dialog( "open" );
});
```

For more info refer this **[documentation here](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form)**